# Puppet - How to use variables defined in manifests with hiera

Tags: puppet, hiera

is there a way to use a variable defined in some manifest with hiera?

This is how I tried it:

**manifest.pp**

```
if $::ipaddress_bond0 {
  $primary_interface = 'bond0'
  notify{"$primary_interface":}
}
else {
  $primary_interface = 'eth0'
  notify{"$primary_interface":}
}
```

**hiera.yaml**

```
some_config:
  server:
    foo:
      bar: "%{::primary_interface}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is [possible](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html#puppet-variables-passed-to-hiera). Look at the example:

**test.pp**

```
class nodes::test
{
  $value1 = 'abc'
  $value2 = hiera('test::value2')
  $value3 = hiera('test::value3')

  notify{ " v1 ${value1}": }
  notify{ " v2 ${value2}": }
  notify{ " v3 ${value3}": }
}

include nodes::test
```

**test.yaml**

```
test::value2: "%{value1}"
test::value3: "%{value4}"
```

**run test:**

```
puppet apply  test.pp
```

> Notice:  v1 abc
>
> Notice:  v2 abc
>
> Notice:  v3

Keep in mind that using puppet variables in hiera is a [really bad practice](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html#best-practices).

Comment: Thx for the fast answer and pointing out that this seems to be a bad solution. The reason for me trying to do this was to ensure that I always get the ipadress of `eth0` or `bond0` and not have to "hope" that the value in `$::ipaddress` is correct. Do you have experience if `$::ipaddress` is a secure solution to get the IP of `eth0` or `bond0` instead of having randomly the ip of e.g. `eth1` sometimes? I can't use `$::ipaddress_eth0` or `$::ipaddress_bond0` since this is too static for my case.

Comment: According to description: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/2.4/core_facts.html#ipaddress _"On the Unixes does an ifconfig, and returns the first non 127.0.0.0/8 subnetted IP it finds."_

Comment: That what I also read - but the thing is that it might happen - because of e.g. strange udev rules that `eth1` comes in front of `eth0` since facter seems to just run `Facter::Util::IP.exec_ifconfig(["2>/dev/null"]` and takes the first non 127.x address `if match and not /^127\./.match(match[1])
          ip = match[1]
          break
        end`

Since the advise in the documentation is to better use custom facts I created a fact with the above logic that I first tried to use in the manifest.

Thx again for pointing me in the right direction.